# new layout vs MVC in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning RoR, and I wanted to know if I want to make a page like google's homepage, must I use Model+Controller+view? or can I use a new Layout (this is because I dont need any DB or entity to save the search query)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need to generate a model**, but you do still need a controller and the relevant views.   If you want a bunch of static pages, you might have a Pages controller and in there you'll have methods set up for the different pages you want.  Match each of those methods with views of the same name.

Layouts are more like base view templates.  A simple app might only have one layout.

See [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info.

First though if you're serious about learning rails I'd suggest working through a tutorial like Hartle's Rails Tutorial:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book - it'll take you through all the basics like this and more.